# DrizzleORM use a unique index in conflict updates

Tags: typescript, postgresql, drizzle-orm

Given the following table:

| user_id | year | roles (array) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2024 | [defender] |
| 0 | 2023 | [attacker] |
| 1 | 2024 | [defender] |

You can observe that we should have a unique entry for each user and year. So this table is correct, but inserting `| 0 | 2024 | attacker |` should replace update the first row instead.

To my knowledge, this means i should create a `unique index` for these, which I've done in drizzle as follows:

```
export const pianiExtra = pgTable(
  'players',
  {
    userId: uuid('user_id')
      .notNull()
      .references(() => users.id, { onDelete: 'cascade' }),
    year: bigint('year', { mode: 'number' }).notNull(),
    roles: roles('roles').array().notNull(),
  },
  (t) => ({
    playersUniqueIndex: unique('players_unique_index').on(t.userId, t.year),
  }),
);
```

Which brings me to the insert query:

```
const input = {
    userId: 0,
    year: 2024,
    roles: [defender, attacker]
}

const result = await ctx.db
      .insert(players)
      .values(input)
      .onConflictDoUpdate({
        target: [players.userId, players.year],
        set: input,
      })
      .returning({ id: pianiExtra.id });
```

There are two things that don;t quite make sense to me here:

1. I would expect to pass the newly created index instead of the properties array in `onConflictDoUpdate -> target`.
2. if I run this, I get a `there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`, which I suspect is related to the target as well.